# vim match block / partial column for highlighting (like visual block selection)

Tags: vim

Since `vim 7.3` you can highlight a virtual column via the `colorcolumn` option.
But I only want to highlight a column for example from line 7 to 16 like shown below in orange:

[image: Example of block highlighting]

It would for example be sufficient, if I could add an additional block highlighting like what you can see while in visual block mode (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>).

I tried to do this with the `:match` command but there you can only kind-of replicate the `colorcolumn` option by using `\%<col>v`. I wasn't able to limit the lines it is operating on and unfortunately it also doesn't match virtual characters after the end of a line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can "chain" columns/lines atoms to define a rectangle:

```
:call matchadd("Error", '\%>5l\%<10l\%>15c\%<20c')
```

That snippet will highlight a 4x4 rectangle between `6,16` and `9,19`:

[image: example]

Keep in mind that `\%>xl`, `\%<xl`, `\%>xc`, and `\%>xc` all work *before* and *after* the given line/column number so you'll need a bit of (basic) calculation.

Comment: @romaninl Thank you, that's a good starting point! Have you got any idea how this could be expanded so that it highlights characters after the end of a line? (like `colorcolumn`)

Comment: `matchadd()` is only able to match characters that exist in the buffer, so unlike `'colorcolumn'`, you cannot match beyond the end of the line.